# Cannot add item to a list

Tags: list, development, feature

I can create a list and add a custom column to it but there are no items present in the list when I try to add them programmatically. Below is the code snippet.

```
Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("TestList", "TestList", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
SPList list = web.Lists[listId];
list.OnQuickLaunch = false;
list.Fields.Add("Enabled", SPFieldType.Boolean, true);
list.Update();

SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
item["Title"] = "ABC";
item["Enabled"] = true;
list.Update();

item = list.AddItem();
item["Title"] = "DEF";
item["Enabled"] = true;
list.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

> item.Update()

instead of:

> list.Update()

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below :

```
            SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
            itemToAdd["Title"] = "Test Title";
            itemToAdd["Description"] = "Test Description";
            itemToAdd.Update();
```

Comment: Please add useful parts of the post in your answer, as link-only answers tend to get void if the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Your siteurl"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPList list = web.Lists["Your listName"];
                SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
                item["Name"] = txtName.Text;
                item["Address"] = txtAdd.Text;
                item["Phone"]=txtPhn.Text;
                item.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
```